# How much did Tokuchi gain per game?

Tags: one-outs

My copy has subtitles on it but it drastically changes from million to billions between games, which makes me believe the subs aren't correct. Could anyone here point me somewhere or tell me how many outs/runs and what multipliers are on which game? I just need this for the anime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [One Outs Fandom](https://oneouts.fandom.com/wiki/Toa_Tokuchi),

| VS | Sum Earned (yen) |
| --- | --- |
| Bloomers | 105million |
| Fingers | 135m |
| -- (Unknown) | 30m |
| Eagles | 150m |
| Mariners | 135m |
| Mariners | 180m |
| Mariners | 1400m |
| Bugaboos | 2065m |
| BlueMars | 160m |
| **Total** | **4360m** |

Comment: ah so some billions were actually correct namely 1.4b and 2.065b ? (i saw one out exactly 1 decade ago. forgot already.)